# Save cycles material with mask as image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, masking

I want to export this texture as an image so I can use it in unity. How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: Click on the "Image" button next to the picture's name and there will be a save option.

Comment: That saves the mask. I want to save the green image.

Comment: Then with diffuse baking.